# Is it possible to emit a mapping?

Tags: solidity, events, mapping

I have a mapping in my code that maps an address of a recycler to a plastic bottle address as below.

```
mapping (address => address)plasticBale;
```

Is there a way I could emit this mapping? or do I have to emit each recycler address and bottles address in separate events?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enumerate the populated values of a mapping because you cannot know which keys exist. You can't know which keys exist because, technically, they all exist - most have default zeroish values.

If you need to know which keys are populated, you will have to store them elsewhere, for example, a dynamic array. If you also need to be able to remove keys from the set, then you need a pattern like CRUD: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-epilogue-e563e794fde

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Emit Keyword in solidity is used to trigger an event, not mapping.
To use emit in our smart-contract, we use:

```
emit EventName();
```

This EventName() is an event that needs to be declared in the smart-contract, or at least be imported into it.

In your case, you have a mapping that maps an address of the recycler to the plastic bottle address.

```
mapping (address => address)plasticBale;
```

This means that you are storing key as address type and value also as an address type.
To use this, you will need to include a code something like the following in one of the functions of your smart contract:

```
plasticBale[recycler_address]=plasticBottle_address;
```

If you want to include this in an event and emit it, you will need to write a custom event, something like:

```
event RecycleStart(
    address recyclerAddress,
    address bottleAddress,
    uint256 scheduledDate
);
```

As you can see, I haven't used mapping. Mappings cannot be created dynamically, you have to assign them from a state variable.
But if the event is declared as above, you can easily emit it in any function like:

```
   function startRecycle(uint256 scheduledDate) public returns(bool success) {
      emit RecycleStart(recyclerAddress,bottleAddress,scheduledDate);
   }
```